# What is the best way to establish wireless communication between the Lilypad and a Mac?

Tags: bluetooth, electronics, system-design, wireless

I want to build a wearable device for a dancer using the Lilypad and I need to first send the programme from my Mac to the Lilypad board and then transfer the data read by sensors back to my Mac.

I want to know what is the best wireless solution to use here. I've seen various options such:

- the Xbee or Bluetooth modules (http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/bluetooth-mate-silver)

Comment: Have you considered using one of those 315MHz or 433MHz modules with a UART?

Comment: What is "best?" Can you please add your requirements (price, range, speed, size, etc.)...

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin The size is important to me because it is a wearable device. But what I want to know is which the most reliable one.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a hc-06 module very successfully. http://www.dx.com/p/hc-06-wireless-bluetooth-serial-pass-through-module-for-arduino-works-with-official-arduino-board-238364#.VLg153WjlIc

Connect pins to +5v, Gnd, and digital pins 0 and 1 (rx & tx).

Do not try to connect to USB and this at the same time, as communication will get garbled.